# What are holonomic constraints?

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to understand what holomic constraints are mathematically. [Wikpedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holonomic_constraints) says:

> In classical mechanics, holonomic constraints are relations between the position variables (and possibly time) which can be expressed in the following form:
>
> ${\displaystyle f(q_{1},q_{2},q_{3},\ldots ,q_{n},t)=0}$
>
> where ${\displaystyle \{q_{1},q_{2},q_{3},\ldots ,q_{n}\}}$ are the $n$ coordinates which describe the system.

This denifition is very vague to me because unless you define $f$ I can't see the "form" they are talking about.

My question: I've a particle of mass, $m$, is constrained to move under gravity on the surface of a cone defined by the equation $x^2 +y^2 =z^2$ for $z \ge 0$. How would I determine/prove whether or not this is holomonic constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the particle is constrained to be *alway on* the cone, then you have holonomic constraints.  If instead the particle simply cannot go *inside* the cone (but can "jump off"), then those are non-holonomic constraints.

Clearer examples:

- standard block sliding along an undulating track is non-holonomic.  After all, if the track drops away too quickly, the block will fly off.
- a bead (with hole) sliding along a wire (through its middle) is holonomic.  No matter how much the wire curves, the bead will always stay on.

At base, the difference is expressed mathematically as the difference between $=$ and $\geq$....

Comment: Thanks. I get it now I think.

Answer (score 0):

A holonomic constraint is an integrable constraint, or also in other words, offer restrictions to generalized positions. Ex. The constraint in the plane movement

$$
x_1 \dot x_1 + x_2\dot x_2 = 0
$$

This is a holonomic constraint because it comes from

$$
\frac{d}{dt}(x_1^2+x_2^2)=0\Rightarrow x_1^2+x_2^2=C
$$

The constraint is non-holonomic when it can't be represented as a derivative regarding time from an integral expression, or in other words, offer restrictions between generalized positions and generalized velocities.

Ex. From a skate movement along a line with direction $\theta$

$$
\dot x_1 = v\cos\theta\\
\dot x_2 = v\sin\theta
$$

after division we have

$$
\dot x_2 -\dot x_1\tan\theta=0
$$

This relationship cannot be integrated because $\theta$ is independent of $x_1, x_2$