# holonomic or nonholonomic constraint

Tags: differential-geometry, education, classical-mechanics

Consider the Lagrangian
$L(x, y, z, \dot{x}, \dot{y}, \dot{z}) = 1/2 m ( \dot{x}^ 2 + \dot{y}^2 + \dot{z}^2 )− mgz$
with the constraints
$y\dot{x} − x\dot{y} = 0.$
How can I prove that these constraints holonomic or nonholonomic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken $\frac{1}{xy}\left(y\dot x-x \dot y\right) = \frac{\dot x}{x}-\frac{\dot y}{y} = 0$ we observe that this comes from $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln x-\ln y\right)$ then it is an integrable constraint over the positional variables $x,y$ thus it is a holonomic constraint $\ln x-\ln y=C$ See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616185/what-are-holonomic-constraints/3617099#3617099)

Comment: I really appreciate! But the second part of this question says “write down the dynamic non holonomic equations” How should I answer, while as you said the constraint is holonomic!?

Comment: Now you have two opinions. Decide by yourself.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Please. See in the textbook what holonomy means and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I did it; I think the answer of second part is given by “Lagrange–d’Alembert equations” or “The method of Lagrange multipliers”, which is lead to $ m \double dot{x} + \lambda \dot{y} = 0 & m \double dot{y} + \lambda \dot{x} = 0 & m \double dot{z}= 0,$ Am I right?

Comment: The last equations is $m\ddot z +m g  = 0$

Comment: Yes, you’re right! Thank you very much.